# Select based on column of field names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to be able to union multiple tables to get a common picture of what a user did across all tables in my db. All of my tables have 'Terminal' and 'CreateDate' as the common fields.

The ultimate goal of this is to pivot the tables and union them without actually using PIVOT or UNPIVOT because I do not want to call out EVERY column in EVERY table manually in my SQL. I though about using sys.columns and sys.tables to somehow select all fields from a table dynamically but can't seem to wrap my brain around it. So the schema would be something like below.

| Table | DateTime | Field | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| userhistory | 12/31/2020 11:35:16 PM | logonoff | on |
| event | 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM | emergencyType | Fire |
| event | 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM | createDate | 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM |
| event | 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM | respondingAgency | FD |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:01:30 AM | respondingUnit | FireTruck1 |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:01:30 AM | createDate | 1/1/2021 12:01:30 AM |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:01:30 AM | unitStatus | Dispatched |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:02:30 AM | respondingUnit | FireTruck1 |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:02:30 AM | createDate | 1/1/2021 12:02:30 AM |
| unithistory | 1/1/2021 12:02:30 AM | unitStatus | Canceled |
| event | 1/1/2021 12:02:35 PM | closeDate | 1/1/2021 12:02:35 PM |
| userhistory | 1/1/2021 12:02:36 PM | logonoff | off |

I've created a stored procedure that allows me to see the table name and datetime. All of my tables have a datetime field but a varying number of fields. Here is SP:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TerminalHistoryTimeline]

    @Terminal varchar(100), 
    @StartDate datetime2(0),
    @EndDate datetime2(0)

    AS

    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select 'tableA' TableName, createDate  from tableA where terminal = @Terminal and createDate between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2 
    union all
    select 'tableB' TableName, createDate  from tableB where terminal = @Terminal and createDate between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2 
    union all
    select 'tableC' TableName, createDate  from tableC where terminal = @Terminal and createDate between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2 

    option(recompile)

    END
```

I guess I'm unsure of how to add in my 'Field' and 'Data' columns to this SP

Comment: Is the data set you've given us the expected results or the sample data? What does the other look like?

Comment: that is the expected result

Comment: *"What does the other look like?"*

Answer (score 0):

Row—>for json—>openjson()=unpivot (or xml instead of json)..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c40c85e5a04081b06b89f6297e31f99d).. [values() instead of union could be used too].

```
select top(5) 'x' as terminal, dateadd(second, checksum(newid())%10000, getdate()) as _date, *
into t1
from sys.all_objects;

select top(2) 'x' as terminal, dateadd(second, checksum(newid())%10000, getdate()) as _date, *
into t2
from sys.all_columns;


select 't1' /*<--!*/ as tbl, _date, o.[key] as colname, o.value as colvalue
from t1 /*<--!*/  as t 
cross apply openjson((select t.* for json path,without_array_wrapper)) as o
where terminal = 'X'
and o.[key] not in ('_date','terminal')
union all
select 't2' /*<--!*/  as tbl, _date, o.[key] as colname, o.value as colvalue
from t2 /*<--!*/ as t
cross apply openjson((select t.* for json path,without_array_wrapper)) as o
where terminal = 'X'
and o.[key] not in ('_date','terminal');
```